# Is there an extention like LESS for CSS but for SQL?

Tags: sql, extend

Is there an extention for SQL available that extends the syntax similar to what LESS does with CSS?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the functionality you're requesting? :)

Comment: Unlike CSS, SQL is already a language capable of doing many things. We are left to guess at what you want to do but feel you cannot.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for an ORM?

Comment: No definitely not a ORM. Just scipting capabilities

Comment: @CoBolt: I believe he's looking for syntactic sugar for SQL.

Answer (score 1):

LESS generates CSS. Just as PHP can generate HTML. So you are looking for an SQL generating language. And you are lucky: Many languages can do that; PHP, Java, C#, ... Well, I guess more or less any programming language out there can.

Actually you wouldn't even usually use SQL without one. You as a programmer can use SQL directly, yes, but whenever a user shall enter data into a database you would usually provide a program (written in some programming language) for them. Inside such program you will use SQL, either with fixed SQL statements or with dynamically constructed statements, often a mix of both.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do calculations, have variables, etc. in your SQL, you'd probably be best served with PL/SQL.

Comment: You can do calculations and have variables in regular SQL.

Comment: I want to have the flexibility for variables in combination with powershell. The stuff with EXEC seems to boring to me. The resulting code is hard to read

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? SQL is processed by the query engine of the RDBMS that you transmit it to.